# How to update libglib without updating everything?

Tags: package-management, updates, lubuntu, glib

I am asking this because I was downloading midori browser for lubuntu 14.04.5 (without ppa) and a dependency error occurred. libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.41.1).

```
Package Installer
package: midori
status:Error
Dependency is
not satisfiable:
libglib2.0-0
(>=2.41.1)
```

So is there a way to update just glib?

Comment: you can download it from the repo that has it (xenial has 2.48) and install from the .deb package  However, it is likely that anything depending on libglib2 will also need to be upgraded to use the new version..

Comment: I just downloaded an older version of midori, version 4.5 works fine